# Code prints 'Invalid input' after all of inputs in 'Rock-paper-scissor' game in python

Tags: python, if-statement, input

I printed a code, but after any of input you write, it says who win and 'Invalid Input', i don't get what am I doing wrong? Can someone help me?

````
import random
while True: 
user_move = str(input())
user_move = user_move.lower()

choices= ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

computer_choice = random.choice(choices)

if user_move in choices:
    if user_move == computer_choice:
        print(f'There is a draw ({user_move})')
    if user_move == 'rock':
        if computer_choice == 'paper':
            print(f'Sorry, but the computer chose {computer_choice}' )
        elif computer_choice == 'scissors':
            print(f'Well done. The computer chose {computer_choice} and failed')
    if user_move == 'paper':
        if computer_choice == 'scissors':
            print(f'Sorry, but the computer chose {computer_choice}')
        elif computer_choice == 'rock':
            print(f'Well done. The computer chose {computer_choice} and failed')
    if user_move == 'scissors':
        if computer_choice == 'rock':
            print(f'Sorry, but the computer chose {computer_choice}')
        elif computer_choice == 'paper':
            print(f'Well done. The computer chose {computer_choice} and failed')
if user_move == '!exit':
    print('Bye!')
else:
    print('Invalid input')  ```
````

Comment: I've removed the [tag:pygame] tag. The [tag:pygame] tag addresses the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library, but is not intended for a game written in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if user_move == '!exit':` should be an `elif`. Then the `else` won’t run if the first `if` did.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong if statement. after the first if (user_move in choices) the next one shouldn't be if but elif. Because it is if it will be untrue and the computer will print the else code.

p.s. input() is a string by default so you don't have to write str(input())

Answer (score 0):

replace [ if user_input == '!exit:' ]
with [ elif user_input == '!exit:' ].

Look more into how indentation and if->elif->else statements work in python.